# Save radiogroup state on activity change

Tags: android, listview

I know there have been posts on how to save radiogroup states on activity change via SharePrefs.  My problem is slightly different.  I have a listview that generates multiple radiogroups dynamically.  How can I make sure when a user leaves the current activity that each of the listview radiogroups are saved?? Below is my current adapter class showing my getView method.

```
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View v = convertView;

  final ViewHolder holder;
  if(v == null) {
     v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_car, parent, false);
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.txtCarName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_car_name);
     holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.scale);

     holder.radioGroup.setTag(position);
     v.setTag(holder);


  }
  else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
  }

  // fill row data
  final Car currentItem = getItem(position);
  if(currentItem != null) {
     holder.txtCarName.setText(currentItem.getCar());
     holder.radioGroup.setTag(currentItem.getAnswer());
  }


  holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
  holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();

  if(checked.indexOfKey(position)>-1){
     holder.radioGroup.check(checked.get(position));
  }else{
     holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
  }

  holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        String Answer = null;
        if(checkedId>-1){
           checked.put(position, checkedId);


           switch (checkedId) {
              case R.id.a1:
                 Answer = "r1";
                 break;
              case R.id.a2:
                 Answer = "r2";
                 break;
              case R.id.a3:
                 Answer = "r3";
                 break;
              case R.id.a4:
                 Answer = "r4";
                 break;
           }

           db.addListItem(“testCar", Answer, getCurrentTimeStamp());  //<----null object reference happening here


        }else{
           if(checked.indexOfKey(position)>-1)
              checked.removeAt(checked.indexOfKey(position));
        }

     }
     });



  return v;
  }
```

Comment: Car has multiple radio options, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist all states, save them in an SQLite Database. Store each checked/unchecked state as 0/1 value or vice versa.

Here is an example:
Assign a unique id to each listview item which contains multiple radiogroups. Assign a unique id within this listview item to each radiobutton. In the database, have three fields,

```
1. unique listview item id
2. unique radiobutton id
3. state (0/1)
```

If you just want to store the state across an orientation change and are not concerned about persisting all states, then another way is to use a retained fragment. This fragment will have a suitable data structure (I will leave that upto you to decide which one to use) that contains all your radiobutton states and is retained across orientation changes.

Comment: Do you have any code you can share regarding the above?